# Importing a Swift class of a framework in Objective-C (test) code

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xctest

I'm trying to import a Swift class from my framework `MyFramework` in my unit test code:

In my **Objective-C test file**, I do:

```
@import MyFramework;
```

This line causes a compilation error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework': 'src/core-ios/MyFramework/Classes/MyFramework-Bridging-Header.h'
```

inside the "MyFramework-Swift.h" file. In that file, I can see a plain import from

```
#import "src/core-ios/MyFramework/Classes/MyFramework-Bridging-Header.h"
```

I'm not sure what to do. My framework "defines" modular headers, but it sound like the problem is that bridging header file which is included with its entire path rather than just doing `#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Bridging-Header.h>`.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

While calling swift class in objective c

1. In Bridging-Header add **#import "myClass.h"**. This is objective c class
   where you are using swift class.
2. In myClass.m add **#import < yourProjectName_swift.h >**
3. In myClass.h or myClass.m add "@swiftcalss;"

   first or second point may cause to your error.